# How to extend firebase authentication login session from the client side?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

The question is in the title. I have done some research but it seems like I can't find a solution to extending the life of the login session when using firebase authentication.

Currently, I have a file that logs the user in from the front-end. After logging in with Firebase Authentication, I pass the firebase id token to the server:

```
//[index.php]
 auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    if (user) {

        //Retrieve the firebase id token
        user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {

            //Send the idToken to the server
            sendIdTokenToServer();

        });

    } else {

        //The user is logged out, redirect to login page

    }

});
```

From the server side, I verify the firebase id token, and assign it to `$_SESSION['firsebase_id_token']` if the token is valid.

```
//[server.php]
//Pseudo verifying the token, if the token is valid, record it
if (verifyToken($token)) $_SESSION['firebase_id_token'] = $token;
```

Now, from this point on, I am trying to verify the token before processing anything from the server side. For example:

```
//[test.php]
//Before processing anything, validate the token
if (verifyToken($_SESSION['firebase_id_token'])) {

    //Perform an action because the user is still logged in

} else {

    //Redirect the user to login page because they are logged out/the token cannot be verified

}
```

**I am not certain this is the right approach to the problem (so please suggest the correct approach)**, they are just what I think is right when reading the documentation. All I want to do is to verify the user (that logged in from the client side) from the server side before performing any administrative tasks. The problem is after a very short period of time, the `$token` isn't valid any more, so the request cannot be made.

**How do I extend the firebase id token session from the client side?**

Comment: I'm not understanding what the problem is here.  Firebase Auth sign-ins last forever, until the user signs out, or their refresh token is revoked.  The ID token must be refreshed every 1 hour, which the client SDK handles automatically (no additional code required).  Please edit the question to indicate what exactly are you observing that suggests something different.  It always helps to show code.

Comment: Hi, @DougStevenson. I have reworded the question. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `onAuthStateChanged`, which is only triggered when the user signs in or out, you should be using [`onIdTokenChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth), which is triggered whenever the user's auth token is refreshed (every hour automatically, or on demand when you call [`getIdToken(true)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html#getidtoken)).